# utility/spi_com.h error when compiling Marlin for Arduino mega with Ramps 1.4

Tags: compilation-errors

I am using win 8.1 and trying to load Marlin 2.0.x onto Arduino Mega with an attached Ramps 1.4 board fitted with 3 8825 Drivers. Unfortunately everytime I try to compile It concludes with the following error. Can anyone please help.

```
Alternatives for utility/spi_com.h: 
[]ResolveLibrary(utility/spi_com.h)  -> candidates: []In file included from C:\Users\Dad\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_750275\sketch\src\HAL\STM32\MarlinSPI.cpp:23:0:C:\Users\Dad\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_750275\sketch\src\HAL\STM32\MarlinSPI.h:28:12: fatal error: utility/spi_com.h: 
No such file or directory   #include <utility/spi_com.h>    
        
compilation terminated.
Using library SPI at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Users\Dad\Downloads\arduino-1.8.13-windows\arduino-1.8.13\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Mega or Mega 2560.
```

Answer (score 2):

> trying to load Marlin 2.0.x onto Arduino Mega

I have no specific knowledge of Marlin.

For the moment, I'm ignoring the fact that it seems to be looking for STM32 files which would seem to play no role on an Arduino Mega.

I cloned the Marlin github repo and found no mention of a file "MarlinSPI.h" in the 2.0.x branch.  There is however a MarlinSPI.h in tag 1.1.9.1

You appear to be working with the code for the wrong version (or branch) of Marlin.